# Change forecolor of gridview cell based on condition in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I need to change the gridview cell color to red if the value is `<=0`. I have tried the below piece of code and it doesn't take the cell value of each row.

How can I get each cell value of gridview.

**Code:**

```
 if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
                    {
                        TableCell cell = row.Cells[i];
                        int quantity = int.Parse(cell.Text);
                        if (quantity <= 0)
                        {
                            cell.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the foreground color or access the text, you should use itemtemplate instead of boundField.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status" ControlStyle-Width="75px" >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ParentID") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

and you can bind this variable like

```
 protected void GridView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i =0 ; i <= GridView1.Rows.Count -1 ;i++)
    {
        Label lblparent = (Label)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("Label1");

        if (lblparent.Text == "1")
        {
            GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].BackColor = Color.Yellow;
            lblparent.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        }
        else
        {
            GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].BackColor = Color.Green;
            lblparent.ForeColor = Color.Yellow;
        }

    }
}
```

for more help check this
https://forums.asp.net/t/1747819.aspx?how+to+change+gridview+cell+color+based+on+cell+item

Answer (score 0):

This is the code you are looking for :

```
    Label lblInfo = (Label)gvVisa_Mofa.Rows[i].FindControl("lblInfo");

    if (lblInfo.Text <= "0")
    {
        gvVisa_Mofa.Rows[i].BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#EDA3A3");

    }
```

another method :

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{

    If(Condition True)
    {
        e.Row.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Red 
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your code worked for me. I put it into DataBound event:

```
    protected void GridView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                TableCell cell = row.Cells[i];
                int quantity = int.Parse(cell.Text);
                if (quantity <= 0)
                {
                    cell.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

My gridview code is:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#3AC0F2" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnDataBound="GridView1_DataBound">
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" ItemStyle-Width="30" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="quantity" HeaderText="Quantity" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="number" HeaderText="number" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I think the key is OnDataBound="GridView1_DataBound" on your GridView1